# Speed Test causing weird behavior. Multiplying time spent by 100 in one instance, only 10 in another

Tags: python, performance, unit-testing

I am doing a speed test with three functions, readFile, prepDict and test. Test is simply prepDict(readFile). I am then running these many times with the timeit module.

When I increase the number of loops by a factor of 10, function prepDict takes ~100 times longer, however function test which uses function prepDict only increases by 10.

Here are the functions and tests.

```
def readFile(filepath):
    tempDict = {}
    file = open(filepath,'rb')
    for line in file:
        split = line.split('\t')
        tempDict[split[1]] = split[2]
    return tempDict

def prepDict(tempDict):
    for key in tempDict.keys():
        tempDict[key+'a'] = tempDict[key].upper()
        del tempDict[key]
    return tempDict

def test():
    prepDict(readFile('two.txt'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer(lambda: readFile('two.txt'))
    print 'readFile(10000): ' + str(t.timeit(number=10000))

    tempDict = readFile('two.txt')
    t = Timer(lambda: prepDict(tempDict))
    print 'prepDict (10000): ' + str(t.timeit(number=10000))

    t = Timer(lambda: test())
    print 'prepDict(readFile) (10000): ' + str(t.timeit(number=10000))

    t = Timer(lambda: readFile('two.txt'))
    print 'readFile(100000): ' + str(t.timeit(number=100000))

    tempDict = readFile('two.txt')
    t = Timer(lambda: prepDict(tempDict))
    print 'prepDict (100000): ' + str(t.timeit(number=100000))

    t = Timer(lambda: test())
    print 'prepDict(readFile) (100000): ' + str(t.timeit(number=100000))
```

The results I get are as follows:

```
readFile(10000): 0.61602914474
prepDict (10000): 0.200615847469
prepDict(readFile) (10000): 0.609288647286
readFile(100000): 5.91858320729
prepDict (100000): 18.8842101717
prepDict(readFile) (100000): 6.45040039665
```

And I get similar results if I run it many times. Why does prepDict increases by a factor of ~100, while prepDict(readFile) only increases by a factor of 10, even though it is using the prepDict function?

two.txt is a tabular delimited file with these data points:

```
Item    Title   Hello2
Item    Desc    Testing1232
Item    Release 2011-02-03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your `prepDict` function expands the inputs. Each time you call it in sequence, it has more data to deal with. And that data grows linearly, so the 10000th run takes about 10000x as long as the first.*

When you call `test`, it's creating a new dict each time, so the time is constant.

You can see this pretty easily by changing the `prepDict` tests to run on a new copy of the dict each time:

```
t = Timer(lambda: prepDict(tempDict.copy()))
```

---

By the way, your `prepDict` is not actually growing exponentially** with `number`, just quadratically. In general, when something is growing super-linearly, and you want to estimate the algorithmic cost, you really need to get more than two data points.

---

* That's not *quite* true—it only starts to grow linearly once the time taken for the string and hashing operations (which grow linearly) starts to swamp the time taken for every other operation (which are all constant).

** You didn't mention anything about exponential growth here, but in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180277/why-do-speed-tests-of-functions-not-add-when-nested-python/17180641#17180641) you did, so you may have made the same unwarranted assumption in your real problem.

Comment: Haha, thanks! Stupid mistake. My problem in my actual code is the same thing, the dict changes and then I resubmit it so the code acts much faster because it isn't changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to `prepDict` are not happening in an isolated environment. Each call to `prepDict` modifies `tempDict` -- the keys get a little longer each time. So after 10**5 calls to `prepDict` the keys in `prepDict` are rather large strings. You can see this (copiously) if you put a print statement in `prepDict`:

```
def prepDict(tempDict):
    for key in tempDict.keys():
        tempDict[key+'a'] = tempDict[key].upper()
        del tempDict[key]
    print(tempDict)
    return tempDict
```

The way to fix this is to make sure each call to `prepDict` -- or more generally, the statement you are timing -- does not affect the next call (or statement) you are timing. abarnert has already shown the solution: `prepDict(tempDict.copy())`.

By the way, you could use a `for-loop` to cut down on the code duplication:

```
import timeit
import collections    

if __name__=='__main__':
    Ns = [10**4, 10**5]
    timing = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for N in Ns:
        timing['readFile'].append(timeit.timeit(
            "readFile('two.txt')",
            "from __main__ import readFile",
            number = N))
        timing['prepDict'].append(timeit.timeit(
            "prepDict(tempDict.copy())",
            "from __main__ import readFile, prepDict; tempDict = readFile('two.txt')",
            number = N))
        timing['test'].append(timeit.timeit(
            "test()",
            "from __main__ import test",
            number = N))

    print('{k:10}: {N[0]:7} {N[1]:7} {r}'.format(k='key', N=Ns, r='ratio'))
    for key, t in timing.iteritems():
        print('{k:10}: {t[0]:0.5f} {t[1]:0.5f} {r:>5.2f}'.format(k=key, t=t, r=t[1]/t[0]))
```

yields timings such as

```
key       :   10000  100000 ratio
test      : 0.11320 1.12601  9.95
prepDict  : 0.01604 0.16167 10.08
readFile  : 0.08977 0.91053 10.14
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're reusing `tempDict` for all the calls to `prepDict` when you're testing just `prepDict`. Since `prepDict` loops over all the items in the dictionary it's given, and then basically just increases the length of each string key by one, you eventually end up with a bunch of extremely long keys. As it progresses, this begins to slow down your function because the string concatenation operations are using/re-creating increasingly enormous strings.

It's not a problem in `test` because you reinitialize the dictionary each time.